# AngularJS (HTML, CSS) to pdf in client side

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, pdf

i'm making web for a internet cafe with angularJS.

When user has been registered, they will see their member card in HTML format with button print.
If the button clicks, it will download automatically the member card as a pdf file.

any ide ?

it wil be helpful if you make an example code :)
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) PDF rendering. [rasterize.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js) rasterizes a web page to image or PDF.